# How to add new columns in Matrix?

Tags: matrix

I can't seem to find the way to add new columns for Matrix fieldtype.

[image: Screenshot]

I am using Expression 2.5.5 and Matrix 2.5.1

Comment: Looks like either there will be a js error (check via firebug or console) or u have some custom css override which may be hiding the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by the Matrix theme JS not loading/running, either due to a missing file or a JS error preventing execution.

1. Double check that you've uploaded `themes/third_party/matrix` from the matrix download  to `themes/third_party/` (If the third_party folder doesn’t exist yet, create it.)
2. If that doesn't work, check that there are no JS errors on the field config page, if there are, update your question with them.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that it has something to do with the installation. I uninstalled everything, reinstalled it and I now see the + and - buttons